# The flagpole needs painting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comment-flags

The flag icon which appears when hovering a comment has a pole which is too red:

> [image: too red flag pole]

This is specific to Stack Overflow, e.g. on other site it looks fine:

> [image: valid flag pole]

On SO, the pole is more red, and the flag itself is less red, which makes the overall icon look weird.

Can the SO comment flag icon be the same as on other sites?

Comment: of utter importance ...

Comment: @rene hey, can't let *@alex* report all dem minor bugz... need to report some myself... ;)

Comment: The way you were saying and circling the pole, I thought you were making a claim that the flag itself seeming less red was an optical illusion caused by the pole being discolored, which I totally would have believed if I didn't see your phrase about "and the flag itself is less red".

Comment: @DavyM yeah, wasn't sure how to really report it. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the edit, I failed to find a proper catchy title. :D

Comment: Hmm, I like it the way it is on SO now; normally a pole is made from a different material than the flag, so I think it's normal to have a slightly different color.

Comment: I don't know where to look in the second image.

Comment: @Maroun nowhere, it's the overall icon which just looks better. :) (maybe I should just put the two images together side by side without circles)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No circles, still can't see anything.

Comment: Why is the freehand red circle blue? That circle needs painting!

Comment: @Adinia it's also slightly different in the other sites... and only slightly, on SO the diff is really not slight or minor, that's the problem. :)

Comment: @Cerbrus red circle around red line won't be visible... sometimes we need to adjust.... :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree it's probably a bug if it's different, but I disagree with the opinion that the other version looks better..I would say that one is in need of painting :)

Comment: I am in agreement with @Adinia personally I think our flag is better the other ones, I think the second flag in this question looks "tacky" while the first seems more professional IMHO

Comment: You could switch your browser 180% zoom to normal view with ctrl+0

Comment: @Cerbrus it's not blue - it's actually grey, and it only looks blue due to an optical illusion. :P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress (In case anyone thinks I'm serious, I'm only joking)

Comment: Shouldn't a flag pole be white...

Comment: @James wouldn't it be difficult to see in white background?

Comment: @TGrif I zoomed to 200% on purpose, only to take the screenshot.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: And those shenanigans are exactly why freehand red circles should be red :P

Comment: I swear if this gets "fixed" before the list of libraries in stack snippets gets updated I'm leaving. OK maybe I won't leave, but I'll definitely shake my fist disapprovingly at my monitor.

Comment: @j08691 hey, design is important! ;)

Comment: Just wait until you get a load of the madness at https://physics.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @j08691 For all the non web devs we don't even get cool stack snippets. Fix the flag!

Comment: Congrats, you circled the pole! (over 106 years after [Roald Amundsen boxed it.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amundsen%27s_South_Pole_expedition)

Comment: Well, I think it's just the *right* amount of red. ;) ...Seriously, I actually like the slight contrast between the two shades of red.

Comment: D'oh!  Just rediscovered that the comment flag is **STILL NOT RETRACTABLE**.  Maybe that's why it appears so sun-faded?

Comment: I'm surprised no one has come up with a "flagging-pole" joke yet.

Comment: Why is this a hot post? This could be the least important "bug" of all time

Comment: @iONinja blame the catchy title... Hot Meta Questions are based only on question score, not answers like with HNQ.

Comment: Due to heavy rains the color has come off the flag and stained the pole. The other explanation, that the Pink Puma and Dimitry Politov lost some skin, has been vehemently denied by regulars of the Tavern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was just looking through old bugs for a thing and...yeah, this was fixed (albeit inadvertently) when it was made into an inline SVG.

Comment: Another bug hits the SVG!